# How do I describe integer division in programming language this in Z3?

Tags: z3

I am using SMT solver to help to analyze programs.
In programming languages, the following condition is satisfiable:

```
int x;
if((x/2) * 2 != x)  {
//reachable
}
```

but for the integer type in mathmatics, this is not satisfiable.
Can I use Z3 to describe this?
Thanks.

Comment: I have another question. I check the operations on bit vectors in Z3, there is no div operation. How about I want to know if((x/3) *3 == x) ? this can not be described in bit vector shifting

Answer (score 1):

Your example is also satisfiable in mathematical integer. You can find a model for `x` to be any odd integer.

In Z3, you should use machine integer i.e. [bit-vectors](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h25) for modeling:

```
(declare-const x (_ BitVec 32))
(assert (not (= (bvmul (bvsdiv x (_ bv2 32)) (_ bv2 32)) x)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This example<sup>[rise4fun link](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Kv6L)</sup> is indeed satisfiable.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I mean I used to use (x mod 2 == x) to replace this in programs. And Integer domain is not close for the division operator.

Comment: I have another question. I check the operations on bit vectors in Z3, there is no div operation. How about I want to know    if((x/3) *3 == x) ? this can not be described in bit vector shifting.

Comment: I updated the example to use `bvsdiv`. Using it is more general than using bit shifting.